# How can I pass an unknown object to a method and determine its type?

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass an object to another class in a constructor. But the object being passed in could be 1 of 2 types. How can I determine what the object is in the constructor?

Here is my (non-working) code:

```
public DueDate(object action)
{
    if (action.GetType() == typeof(RigActionClass.RigAction)) // This is a RigAction
    {
        // Constructor logic
    }
    else // This is a UniqueRigAction
    {
        // Constructor logic
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why is what you posted "not working"? If you're getting a compiler error, post it. If it compiles but does something you don't expect at runtime, post both what you expect it to do and what it actually does.

Comment: you need to explain how you want to consume the action argument to expect a proper answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of options that I see off the top of my head. The better solution depends on what you're doing in the logic.

A) Overload your .ctor. This is better if you're manipulating the DueDate in your logic.

```
public DueDate(RigActionClass.RigAction action)
{
    // RigAction logic
}

public DueDate(RigActionClass.UniqueRigAction action)
{
    // UniqueRigAction logic
}
```

B) Create a common base class and put distinct logic into the action. This is better if you're manipulating the Action in your logic. Depending on what you want to accomplish, you may also use an interface instead of the abstract class.

```
abstract class MyAction { public abstract void Init(); }

class RigAction : MyAction
{
    public Init() { /* RigAction Logic */ }
}

class UniqueRigAction : MyAction
{
    public Init() { /* UniqueRigAction logic */ }
}

public DueDate(MyAction action)
{
    action.Init();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you  need get it too complicated as you  can achieve by doing something like this

```
public  class  ActionBaseType
{

}
public class RightAction:ActionBaseType
{

}
public class  UniqueRightAction: ActionBaseType
{

}
```

**to check**

```
public DueDate(ActionBaseType action)
{
  if( action  is  RightAction)
{
   //do here 
}
else 
 //do here 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In c# its simple `if (action is RigActionClass.RigAction)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DueDate(object action)
{
    if (a is RigActionClass.RigAction) // This is a RigAction
    {
        // Constructor logic
    }
    else // This is a UniqueRigAction
    {
        // Constructor logic
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your supposedly "non-working" code is one of the possible correct ways to do this. If you're not getting the result you expect then your code is broken somewhere else, not here.

I just tested this in Linqpad and it definitely works.

```
void Main()
{
  A a = new A();
  B b = new B();
  Print(a);
  Print(b);
}

void Print(object o)
{
  if (o.GetType() == typeof(A))
    "A".Dump();
  else if (o.GetType() == typeof(B))
    "B".Dump();
}

class A
{
}

class B : A
{
}
```

output:

```
A
B
```